# postgres ERROR: lock buffer_content is not held (postgres error XX000)

Tags: c, postgresql, database-cursor

I am using POSTGRES 10.6 compiled on AIX 7.1

I am getting error `XX000` when trying to perform an update. 
I am using C code using libpq libraries in my code. See below error in the postgres log file.

I found that the error is issued from postgres source file:

```
      src/backend/storage/lmgr/lwlock.c (line 1731)
```

Do you have any idea what can be causing this error?

```
2019-03-21 09:08:48 EDT postgres> ERROR:  lock buffer_content is not held
2019-03-21 09:08:48 EDT postgres> STATEMENT:  insert into mxrmen_rec values ($1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,
      $7,$8,$9,$10,$11,$12,$13,$14,$15,$16,$17,$18,$19,$20,$21,$22,$23,$24,$25,$26,$27,$28,$29,
      $30,$31,$32,$33,$34,$35,$36,$37,$38,$39,$40,$41,$42,$43,$44,$45,$46,$47,$48,$49,$50,$51,
      $52,$53,$54,$55,$56,$57,$58,$59,$60,$61,$62,$63,$64,$65,$66,$67,$68,$69,$70,$71,$72,$73,
      $74,$75,$76)
```

I appreciate any help. Let me know if you need more information

Thank you
Faouzi

Comment: That means that there was an attempt to release a light-weight lock that was not held. The lock in question is for a page in shared buffers. Can you share a small code sample that reproduces the error?

Comment: Tha nk you Larenz for the quick reply.I will try to write a small piece of code and will share it. I am currently out of town so I will ask my colleague to prepare it

Comment: The issue was specifically related to Postgres 10.6.

Comment: Are there any GIN indexes involved?

Comment: @FaouziSem were you able to isolate an SQL that could reproduce this? It'd be a big help if we could have a repro for the developers to resolve. If not, any concrete info that could help the next reader, would be very helpful. Thanks.